# how do use pyspark filter when column name has blank

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My pyspark data frame has several columns that has blank in them for e.g. Inbound Delivery ( note space in between). When i'm trying to compare using .filter i'm getting an error . I dont want to redefine the schema removing the blank since i have huge table with almost all have the same space in name. is there a quick way to use filter with name having blank

dfjoin.where ('Inbound Delivery=0090043373' ).show()

Error

---

Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Desktop\spark\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

~\Desktop\spark\spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1424.filter.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input '=' expecting (line 1, pos 16)

Answer (score 1):

For example, this way:

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([("a",), ("b",)], ["column name"])
>>> df.show(False)
+-----------+
|column name|
+-----------+
|          a|
|          b|
+-----------+
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import col
>>> df.filter(col("column name") == 'b').show()
+-----------+
|column name|
+-----------+
|          b|
+-----------+
```